# How to query efficiently in SQLAlchemy for all groups and check whether or not a known user belongs to each

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a many-to-many model like the proverbial users and groups:

```
users_groups_table= Table('users_in_groups', Base.metadata,
    Column('group_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('group.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('user_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    groups = relationship("Group", secondary=users_groups_table, backref="members")

class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'group'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
```

So ultimately, I'm querying for one of these, and want to indicate when a known instance of the other is present in the relationship.

I could do something like:

```
user = session.query(User).get(known_user_id)

groups = session.query(Group).all()
for g in groups:
    if user in g.members:
        # ...
```

However, I feel like this would end up doing a query for each group to get a list of users, which might be a huge list, and doing a test in that, when enough information is known at the onset that I think this whole thing could be formed more efficiently.

I guess I could query for the groups the user belongs to once, and test if each group is in that set.
Is that the best solution though? What if there are TONS of groups and I'm only paging through a subset in my query?

I just feel that I'm missing a better way to structure the initial query to get exactly the data I want without resulting in pythonic member in list tests for every item.

### For example:

Let's say I have a complex query and get back groups with IDs: [100, 500, 999]. And let's say the user is a member of #500, and everything from #1000 to #10000000. I want to get back something like:

```
(group<id 1>, false)
(group<id 500>, true)
(group<id 999, false)
```

Comment: In other words you want to find if a user belongs to all the groups? Or find groups the user does (not) belong to?

Comment: In my bigger picture, I have a lot of groups, and I'm querying a slice of them, and for each of the groups returned I want to know whether or not this user belongs to each of them.

Comment: Still a wee bit confused, so for a set of groups, you want to know if the user belongs to all of them?

Comment: @IljaEverilä No, not "all" I don't want a single yes/no answer to my query, I want to know of the groups returned, which of them the user belongs to. (I added an example)